# asp.net mvc jquery posting multiple hidden fields

Tags: jquery, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-mvc-5

i have this list of hidden fields

```
   <input type="hidden" value="1" id="serviceslist" name="serviceslist" />
   <input type="hidden" value="2" id="serviceslist" name="serviceslist" />
   <input type="hidden" value="3" id="serviceslist" name="serviceslist" />
```

i have add more button which when clicked want to sent the serviceslist to mvc controller. basically i think that i need to send the list as array. how can i do it?

```
  $('#addmoreservices').click(function () {          
     var serviceslist= $("#serviceslist").val()
        $.ajax({
            url: url,
            data: { serviceslist: serviceslist },
            cache: false,
            dataType: "json",
            traditional: true,
            type: "POST",
            success: function (data) {

                alert("dddd");
            },
            error: function (reponse) {
                alert("error : " + reponse);
            }
        });
    });
```

this is my mvc controller

```
 [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult AddmoreServices(List<int> serviceslist)
    {

        return View();
    }
```

Comment: `id` should be unique

Answer (score 3):

You have some errors in your html and js.

First of all, id must be unique:

```
<input type="hidden" value="1" id="val1" />
<input type="hidden" value="2" id="val2" />
<input type="hidden" value="3" id="val3" />
```

The second one, jquery `val()` function gets the current value of the first element in the set of matched elements, not array.

And the third one, is about posting your data on server. By default `jquery.ajax` post's your data in url `contentType='application/x-www-form-urlencoded'`, it should be changed to `application/json`.

```
serviceslist = [$("#val1").val(), $("#val2").val() ,$("#val3").val()];
$.ajax({
   url: url,
   data: serviceslist,
   contentType: 'application/json',
   ....
```

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively you can do by making the button as `submit` like,

```
@using(Html.BeginForm("AddMoreServices", "Your controller name", FormMethod.Post, null)) {

<input type="hidden" value="1" id="val1" name="serviceslist" />
<input type="hidden" value="2" id="val2" name="serviceslist" />
<input type="hidden" value="3" id="val3" name="serviceslist" />

<button type="submit" value="Add More Services"/>

}
```

and your controller action method can be

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult AddMoreServices(FormCollection collection)
{
    try
    {
        string[] test = collection.GetValues("serviceslist");

        // here test[0] will give you the value of `val1`
        // test[1] will give `val2` and test[2] will give `val3`'s values
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        return null;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this,

**HTML :**

```
<input type="hidden" value="1" class="serviceslist" name="serviceslist" />
<input type="hidden" value="2" class="serviceslist" name="serviceslist" />
<input type="hidden" value="3" class="serviceslist" name="serviceslist" />
```

**JQUERY :**

```
$('#addmoreservices').click(function () {          
    var serviceslist= $(".serviceslist").serialize();
    $.ajax({
        url: url,
        data: serviceslist,
        cache: false,
        dataType: "json",
        traditional: true,
        type: "POST",
        success: function (data) {

            alert("dddd");
        },
        error: function (reponse) {
            alert("error : " + reponse);
        }
    });
});
```